# Picking the most items from array 1, less items from array 2 etc

Tags: ruby

How to randomly and infinitely loop through the objects in these arrays according to their "importance"?

```
test = [
  important = [
    "lorem",
    "ipsum"
  ],
  kinda_important = [
    "dolor",
    "sit"
  ],
  not_so_important = [
    "amet",
    "consectetur"
  ]
]

test.shuffle.each do |test|
  sleep 5
  puts test 
end
```

should output ie.:

```
lorem
lorem
sit
ipsum
lorem
ipsum
ipsum
dolor
ipsum
sit
amet
lorem
ipsum
dolor
lorem
sit
...
```

where `important` is outputted most frequently, `kinda_important` less so etc.

Comment: Your execution code (the `test.shuffle.each do |test|` part) won't result in an infinite execution, you'll just get the 3 inner arrays in a random order. How are you getting individual words in an infinite sequence from which you want to choose the most important?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure exactly... working it out while keeping this question open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need to assign some probabilities here to your importance levels. Maybe redefine your data structure like this

```
test = {
  (0..49) => [ # most important
    "lorem",
    "ipsum"
  ],
  (50..79) => [ # semi important
    "dolor",
    "sit"
  ],
  (80..99) => [ # least important
    "amet",
    "consectetur"
  ]
}
```

Then do something like this.

```
while true
  rand = Kernel.rand(100)
  test.each do |range, options|
    if range.include?(rand)
      puts options.sample
    end
  end
end
```

You'll have to edit those percentage chances to your desired randomness.

PS: You could make it slightly more readable by doing `Kernel.rand(100) + 1` (which will generate a number between 1 and 100, rather than 0 and 99) and shifting the ranges up by one: `(1..50)` = 50%, `(51..75)` = 25%, etc. Just a thought.

Comment: Right on point - beautiful code as always and thanks for sharing!

Comment: So basically 25% could be written as `0..25`, `25..50`, `50..75`, `75..100` etc.?

Comment: I think that'll be off by one. Try `0..24, 25..49, 50..74, 75..99`. And then make sure to change to `Kernel.rand(99)`

Comment: Whoops, sorry, stick with `Kernel.rand(100)`. Generates an integer >= 0 and < the number provided. http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand . I'll fix the answer for future viewers.

Comment: By the way is `sample` really needed here?

Comment: The way it is structured right now, yes. `options` is the array of both items, e.g. maybe this one `["lorem", "ipsum"]`. #sample will choose randomly between those two. If you wanted you could put each option on its own probability (half of the combined probability for the two options) and it would result in the same outcome. E.g. `(0..24) => "lorem", (25..49) => "ipsum"` and so on. And then you could delete the `sample` call.

Comment: Must the arrays together make out 100? Ie. 0..20, 20..50, 50..100 -- or can the same be expressed like 0..20, 0..30, 0..50?

Comment: The way it is written now they need to be consecutive, not overlapping. The algorithm picks a random number between 0 and 99 and then checks which range that number belongs to in order to determine what words to sample. If the ranges were overlapping as you wrote, the random number `15` would belong to all of them, and nothing above `50` would trigger any of them.

Comment: Cool. That explains a lot, I was wondering why things were acting funny. Is there no way to express probabilities without having to take all arrays into consideration though?

Comment: Sure, you could do something like the other answer suggested, where you use only probabilities, rather than specific ranges, and build out the ranges in the code. This gist is kinda a combination of that answer and mine. https://gist.github.com/alexcavalli/33a59ac0a43eb31d6080 Excuse the very long variable names, I was shooting for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much! Regarding the long variable names, would it make sense to shorten them like these perhaps? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/77b98de1eb05b5025882

Comment: That's up to you - go with whatever seems like it's clear to you now, and, assuming you might need to change this later, will be clear to you after a year of not looking at it.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, as long as my shortened version doesn't have any logical naming flaws in it. I'll probably know better once I understand the code better. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Come to think of it - is there a way to prevent the same word from repeating itself twice consecutively?

Comment: Of course :) you may want to start a new question, since we're deviating from this one a bit. But try saving off the last word that was used, and looping the sampling code (probably using a `while` loop) until the sample is not the same as the last word that was used.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a correct object for the data.  You might use:

```
test = { important:        ["lorem", "ipsum"],
         kinda_important:  ["dolor", "sit"],
         not_so_important: ["amet", "consectetur"] }
```

You'll need some probabilities:

```
probs = { important: 0.5, kinda_important: 0.3, not_so_important: 0.2 }
```

We can now generate the desired random variates (for an arbritrary number of elements in `hash` and `probs`):

```
def deal(hash, probs, nbr)
  last = 0.0
  choices = probs.each_with_object({}) do |(group, prob),choices|
    choices[last + prob] = group
    last += prob
  end 
  nbr.times.map do
    rn = rand
    hash[choices.find { |cum,ch| rn <= cum }.last].sample
  end
end

deal(test, probs, 15)
  #=> ["amet", "amet", "consectetur", "dolor", "lorem", "dolor", "amet", 
  #    "sit", "sit", "lorem", "lorem", "lorem", "lorem", "ipsum", "ipsum"]
```

Here:

```
choices
  #{0.5=>:important, 0.8=>:kinda_important, 1.0=>:not_so_important}
```

Let's try it:

```
n = 10_000
a = deal(test, probs, n)
a.uniq.map { |s| [s, a.count(s).to_f/n] }.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
  #=> {"ipsum"      =>0.2541, "lorem"=>0.25,
  #    "dolor"      =>0.1513, "sit"  =>0.1457,
  #    "consectetur"=>0.1016, "amet" =>0.097
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting your code in a `while` loop:

```
while true
 test.shuffle.each do |test|
  puts test 
 end
end
```

Comment: dont randomly update your question like this. It makes my answer completely irrelevant, despite the fact that it answered your initial question. Prefer asking a new question if you have new conditions