# Randomly, probabalistically and infinitely execute methods from external files

Tags: ruby

Expanding on [Picking the most items from array 1, less items from array 2 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28786166/picking-the-most-items-from-array-1-less-items-from-array-2-etc) -- **anybody know how to randomly, probabalistically and infinitely execute methods from external files?**

### Expected behavior

```
50% my_lorem
50% my_lorem
25% my_sit
50% my_ipsum
50% my_lorem
50% my_ipsum
50% my_ipsum
25% my_dolor
50% my_ipsum
25% my_sit
10% my_amet
50% my_lorem
50% my_ipsum
25% my_dolor
50% my_lorem
10% my_consectetur
25% my_sit
...
```

### Current behavior

```
50% my_lorem
50% my_ipsum
25% my_dolor
25% my_sit
10% my_amet
10% my_consectetur
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
...
```

### **lorem.rb**

```
def my_lorem
  puts "50% my_lorem"
  sleep 2
end
```

### **main.rb**

```
require_relative "lorem.rb"
require_relative "ipsum.rb"
require_relative "dolor.rb"
require_relative "sit.rb"
require_relative "amet.rb"
require_relative "consectetur.rb"

scripts = {
  (0..50) => [ #most probable
    my_lorem,
    my_ipsum
  ],
  (0..25) => [ #less probable
    my_dolor,
    my_sit
  ],
  (0..10) => [ #least probable
    my_amet,
    my_consectetur
  ]
}

while true
  rand = Kernel.rand(100)
  scripts.each do |range, options|
    if range.include?(rand)
      puts options.sample
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems.

First and foremost, this block of code *invokes* each of your methods:

```
scripts = {
  (0..50) => [
    my_lorem, # invoke my_lorem, store return value in hash
    my_ipsum # invoke my_ipsum, etc
  ],
  # ...
```

Secondly, each of your methods doesn't *return* a string, it `puts` a string, so when each method is invoked above, it outputs its string exactly once. This is why you're seeing any output at all in your program.

Third, you're using `puts` twice. If your code for randomly selecting a method worked, you would be using `puts options.sample`, which itself already `puts` a string to the string. You need to fix your methods to return a string if your intent is to write that string to the console outside the method.

So, first: Create a hash with ranges pointing to methods, instead of  *invoking* all of your methods and storing the return values in the hash. You cannot reference a method in Ruby just by using it's name, that *invokes* the method. If you want to obtain and store the a handle to the method itself, you need to use the `method` method:

```
scripts = {
  (0..50) => [ #most probable
    method(:my_lorem),
    method(:my_ipsum)
  ],
  (0..25) => [ #less probably
    method(:my_dolor),
    method(:my_sit)
  ],
  (0..10) => [ #least probable
    method(:my_amet),
    method(:my_consectetur)
  ]
}
```

Second, you can invoke the methods using `.call`, and thirdly, you can choose whether to put the `puts` inside the method and have the method not return, or have the `puts` outside the method and have the methods return string:

```
# ...
if range.include?(rand)
  options.sample.call
end
# ...
```

Comment: By the way, if I do `puts options.sample` I get ie. `#<Method: Object#my_lorem>`. Is there a way to make it output `my_lorem` only?

Comment: @MarkBoulder You're not invoking the method if you're using `puts options.sample`. As I said, use `.call`: `puts options.sample.call`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, but managed to get it working with `puts options.sample.name`. Thanks again!